# Twitter Oauth (PHP) - Get latest tweet with links

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am using the [Twitter oauth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth).

I have it setup and can pull the latest Tweet from the users timeline.  My problem is getting the links to show up.  This all comes back as plain text. Need to have things such as usernames (@user) link to their pages, hashtags linking and any URLs linking up as well.

After verifying credentials, I am using the following code to pull the latest user Tweet.

```
$statuses = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' =>   
$twitterUser, 'count' => $count));

foreach ($statuses  as $status) {

echo $status->text . "<br>";

}
```

Comment: Twitter api doesnt provide that, try to check the library if it contain the utility that you need, or you can make it by your self using preg_match(). good luck !

Comment: Thanks.. I found a pre written function that seems to do exactly what I need.

Comment: http://mardix.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/php-function-to-convert-link-in-twitter-status-to-url/

Answer (score 1):

For both technical and terms-of-service reasons, you'll need to use the `entities` block for this.

```
"entities": {
  "url": {
    "urls": [
      {
        "expanded_url": null,
        "url": "http://dev.twitter.com",
        "indices": [
          0,
          22
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "description": {
    "urls": [

    ]
  }
},
```

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities